# I get the following error AttributeError: __enter__ when only using one with block

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to save the file lines in a list I with the following code I get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emiel\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Making_a_list_from_file.py", line 7, in <module>
    with filename as file_object:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

This is the code:

```
with filename as file_object:
    lines=file_object.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is telling you that the object you're using in the `with` statement is not of the right type. `__enter__` is one of the methods called as part of the context manager protocol, and the type you're using doesn't have that method.

Based on your variable name, it looks like you may be using a file name where you want to be using a file object. The error message will then make sense, as strings are not context managers the way file objects are. Try changing your `with` statement to:

```
with open(filename) as file_object:
```

Comment: You are correct. Thank you very much for clarifying this! I will accept the answer.